# Wave front set and differential operator

Tags: micro-local-analysis

A simple result of microlocal analysis would be, if P is a differential operator then $WF(Pu) \subseteq WF(u)$, where WF denotes the wave front set of the distribution.
Can anyone give me an example where the inclusion is strict.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $P = 0$ and $u$ anything with a non-empty wavefront set?

Comment: If you don't like $P =0$: work on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $P = \partial_y$ and $u = H(x)$ where $H$ denotes the Heaviside function.

Comment: @hsm: If you have equality, then $P$ is hypoelliptic, by definition. In order to have strict inclusion, then, it is enough to choose $P$ not hypoelliptic; the example that immediately comes to mind is the wave operator $P = \partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2$.